# The moon in the future

Tags: astronomy, kiddush-levanah, literalism, latid-lavo-future

We say in Kiddush Levanah,

> יהי רצון מלפניך...למלאת פגימת הלבנה ולא יהיה בה שום מיעוט
>
> May it be Your will...to fill the reduction of the moon, and that there should be no diminishment in it.

Since the waxing and waning of the moon is a result of its orbiting the Earth, does this mean that it will remain on the opposite side of the Earth from the Sun in the future?

Comment: Sincethis is a ruchnius (spiritual) reference and refers to the discussion of the monn being "diminished" when it complined, the it would not necessarily mean the physical rotation of the moon around the earth.

Comment: @sabbahillel If you could find a source for that, it could be the makings of an answer. (Let me guess, Rambam?)

Comment: @DonielF memory. That is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @sabbahillel Let me guess, you only know that this is spiritual *because of* science. Some hundreds of years ago you'd be absolutely sure it is all physical. That's a very common getaway from the truth - each time something doesn't make sense we claim - it's spiritual. As the creation MUST mimic the spiritual, Doniel's right, we should expect the Moon to shine 24/7 physically, otherwise, there'll be no connection between Israel and the Moon.

Comment: Please see what I answered https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106741/15579

Comment: @AlBerko Technically the moon does shine all the time. It is just that we do not see it all the time.